# Google_Http_Request to Google-Drive-API get readable data for response body

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Hello i am making a test request to my google drive via the php library they provide. The request is successful and the data are received but are not readable to humans.

The related document information:

```
MIME type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
```

after making a request via:

```
  $file = $service->files->get($fileId);
  $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
  if ($downloadUrl) {
    $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
    } else {
      // An error occurred.
      return NULL;
    }
   } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return NULL;
   }
```

I get the data of the document, but they look like gibberish to me. Something like :

```
PK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%5E%C3%862%0C%27%27%08mimetypeapplication%2Fvnd.oasis.opendocument.textPK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%18Configurations2%2Ffloater%2FPK%03%04%14%08%08%08%C2%B0brE%27Configurations2%2Faccelerator%2Fcurrent.xml%03PK%07%08%02PK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%1FConfigurations2%2Fimages%2FBitmaps%2FPK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%18Configurations2%2Fmenubar%2FPK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%1CConfigurations2%2Fprogressbar%2FPK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%1AConfigurations2%2Fpopupmenu%2FPK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%18Configurations2%2Ftoolbar%2FPK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%1AConfigurations2%2Fstatusbar%2FPK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE%1AConfigurations2%2Ftoolpanel%2FPK%03%04%14%08%C2%B0brE7%C5%A1%C3%BB%24%E2%80%9E!%E2%80%9E!%18Thumbnails%2Fthumbnail.png%E2%80%B0PNG%20%1A%20IHDR%C3%86%01%08%02g%3F%C5%BE%17!KIDATx%C5%93%C3%AD%5D9%E2%80%99%C3%A2L%13%C3%8D%C5%BD%C3%B8%C2%8F%E2%80%9Ad(8%C3%81p%02%C2%81%C6%92%E2%80%A6%C3%9B%1E%CB%9C%C3%82i%0FS%1E%0E%CB%9C%C3%A0%C2%B5%E2%80%B9%E2%80%A6%03%C5%93%40%7D%02%02C%C3%A2.%C3%BC%C2%B5%2BK%12K%C3%8FW%C3%856%C3%B9%22%C2%A6%E2%80%A1%C3%96RZ%C3%88V%C2%A5%C2%AA%C3%9E%7B%C3%B9%C2%BF%C3%93%C3%A9%04%04%E2%80%9A%3B%C3%BC%C3%AF%C3%91%27%40x7PH%11%1C%C6%92B%C5%A0%C3%A0%18%14R%04%C3%87%20%C2%90%228%06%E2%80%A6%14%C3%811(%C2%A4%08%C5%BDA!Ep%0C%20)%E2%80%9AcPH%11%1C%C6%92B%C5%A0%C3%A0%18%14R%04%C3%87%C2%B8%5BH%1D%C3%A7%C2%9Di%CB%9C-%C3%A2%7B%C3%AE%C3%B9%E2%80%99(%2F%C3%B78%C5%B8%17Ib%5D%C3%B7%C3%B1xl%C2%B5Z%C2%8F%3A%C2%B5%C3%9B%C3%A0%3D%C2%A4v%C2%A3%C2%8F%C3%AE%12%C3%A0%C3%8Fl%3B%CB%86n%C3%9F%25%C2%8D%C5%A0o%C3%98%C3%88%1B%C3%9AJ%26%C3%BD%C2%9D%C3%97s%C3%B4%08s%C3%B9E%E2%80%93%CB%9CPh%CB%86%E2%80%A2%12%C2%AD%C3%9E%20*%C3%A4%C2%A7%24%C2%B1%C2%A3%C3%A78%C3%BF%C3%BC%E2%80%9E%C3%AF%2C%C3%B9%7DL%5D%3C%C2%A2cx%0F%C2%A9%C2%B8%3F%E2%80%BA%7D%C3%B1%7Bs%C5%93%C2%8F%3E%3B%1F%C3%9D%1F%11%5D%C2%AB%C3%AE%C3%B8%07o%C3%B5%C3%A7%C3%8F%C5%B8%C5%B8%C5%B8%1Fu%C3%A7%C3%99.y%E2%80%BA%C3%8F%C3%B1%20%C3%82%5Cl9%C3%9C%C5%BE%5E%C3%B4!%E2%80%A6.%C2%BF%C3%B31n%0F%E2%80%A1%C3%8B%C3%A5~8%E2%80%9E%C3%A5r%3C%060%C2%B7B%5C%3E%C3%8Cfm%C2%B6t%5BD%C2%AB%C3%AE%C3%87%CB%9C%C3%9D%C5%A0%C3%89%C3%A13%C3%9D%C3%B3%C3%9B%C3%82%C2%AF%C5%B8%3D%C2%B6%C5%BDE%C3%B8%3D%C3%897%C3%87%C3%9D!%C3%A0a%C3%8A%C3%B7%17M%C2%A9%3B%C2%A9%C3%AE!%C3%BAl%C3%AE*%3B%20%C2%BB%E2%84%A2%C2%BD%C3%B8%2F%E2%80%9A%C3%B1%C3%B7%C3%B0%C3%BF%E2%80%9DZ%C2%8FWQ%C2%8F%C3%9D%C3%94%C3%A2%C2%B0%E2%80%94K%C3%9Aa%1C%C2%B6%01%C3%B8%C3%85%E2%80%B9%E2%80%B9%5D%E2%80%A1%13H%C3%93%C2%BD%5C%C3%95%E2%80%99%C2%BB%C5%92%E2%80%94%C3%A2%C5%BD%0F%02%C2%B9%C3%A5r%C2%BD%5B%C3%84%2F%19T%C3%BA%C3%B2a%C2%B3b%17%C3%BC%C2%B3%5C%C2%B2%C3%B0X%7C%C3%A5%C3%BB%C3%A5%C3%8F%C3%8Fl%3B%5B%C2%ADA%5C%20%C3%BF%C3%A2%E2%80%A1%C3%9B%1E%C2%A4c%C3%B8YO%E2%80%A1%20V%C3%B1GU%C2%BB%3D%E2%80%BAda%3E%0F%C3%B8%C3%B3.H%C3%B7%7F%E2%82%ACo%20%C2%B3%C3%A2%E2%80%9D%14%C2%A3%C2%8Fu%7F%C3%91_%E2%80%BA%C2%90%C3%A21d%C3%9FO%C2%B3%04z%C6%92%3F%C2%AB%7B%5D%C2%B2%C3%BF%C2%A7%C3%94B%3D%60%C3%A2EV%06E
```

I assume setting a content type may solve this and actually get back readable information (the content of the file) that are there on this .odt file.

The general idea is to use google drive as document parser if possible, so i can work with their content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used `getDownloadUrl` so what gets downloaded is exactly the same as what got uploaded. If you upload an ODT document without conversion, then when you download it you also get an ODT document.

It sounds like what you meant to do was to upload it with convert=true so it  becomes a Google Doc, and then download it using one of the `exportLink` properties.

Comment: The main idea is that i want to work with the content of the file while keeping it on the same format. If converting it to a google doc will allow me to actually be able to work with its content and later on export it to .odt that would be fine with me (although i assume i will be facing the same problem). Bottom line is that i want to be able to read the data of the file i n a readable format and work with its text   before reuploading them at the end.

Comment: you'll need to provide more detail on what you mean by "work with the content". Basically Drive gives you two choices. Either 1/ you upload the file without conversion in which case Drive is simply storage and your app will download it in exactly the same format that it was uploaded in. or 2/ you convert it to a Google Doc, in which case in can be edited through drive.google.com and exported back to a format such as .odt, .pdf, etc

Comment: By work with the content, i want to be able to read the data of the file no matter the type it is. Afterwards lets say for example show its content on the screen through a web application. Users can edit it and save it. The general idea is to be able to let the users to upload their files no matter the extension and let the web application compare them, edit them and so on through the web interface. Thinking of something like an universal parser. Hope i was clear enough.

Comment: That's pretty broad, and as stated, difficult if not impossible. Your two choices are as above. You'll just need to experiment with both and see which fits whatever it is you're trying to achieve. If you convert, the files is editable, but only through drive.google.com. If it's a doc, you can export it as HTML into a contenteditable div and then re-import. Might work for you but the fidelity isn't all that.

Comment: I understand that it is hard, that's why I am asking for help here :). Nevertheless the main thing i need to do now its simply be able to convert the raw odt data in a readable format avoiding any additional libraries. My final target can be achieved by utilizing the LO libraries but i wanted to avoid that :)

Comment: Not much more I can add to "You'll just need to experiment with both and see which fits whatever it is you're trying to achieve"